# "uninitialized local variable" error when using pointers for function arguments

Tags: c++

I have a function:

```
VOID GetOSVersion(PDWORD major, PDWORD minor, PDWORD build)
{
    OSVERSIONINFO osver;
    ZeroMemory(&osver, sizeof(OSVERSIONINFO));
    osver.dwOSVersionInfoSize = sizeof(OSVERSIONINFO);
    GetVersionEx(&osver);
    if(major)
    *major = osver.dwMajorVersion;
    if(minor)
    *minor = osver.dwMinorVersion;
    if(build)
    *build = osver.dwBuildNumber;
}
```

And I wanted to invoke it like this:

```
PDWORD major;
PDWORD minor;
PDWORD build;
GetOSVersion(major, minor, build);
```

I get an error for all the three arguments:

> uninitialized local variable

In my head it went like: I declare `major`, `minor`, `build`, and they get filled in the function. Space is already allocated for them during the first three lines of the invoking code.

I am surely missing something here. Could somebody please explain this for me?

Comment: You pass all the three variables major, minor and build as non-reference to the function, without initialising them. Since the function deals with the values of those variables this doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is there:

```
DWORD major;
DWORD minor;
DWORD build;
GetOSVersion(&major, &minor, &build);
```

Fix:

```
VOID GetOSVersion(PDWORD major, PDWORD minor, PDWORD build)
{
    OSVERSIONINFO osver = {};
    osver.dwOSVersionInfoSize = sizeof(OSVERSIONINFO);
    GetVersionEx(&osver);
    if(major)
    *major = osver.dwMajorVersion;
    if(minor)
    *minor = osver.dwMinorVersion;
    if(build)
    *build = osver.dwBuildNumber;
}

DWORD major = 0;
DWORD minor = 0;
DWORD build = 0;
GetOSVersion(&major, &minor, &build);
```

PDWORD is pointer to DWORD. All three parameters are output parameters. In C/C++, it's a common usage: if you want to return more then one value from a function, you need pass pointer (or reference too in case of c++) to a variable:

```
int var = 0;
if(some_function_that_can_fail_and_write_result(&var))
 ;//do something
```

In your case you are passing uninitialized pointer to a function by value. It's the same as:

```
void foo(int parameter);
// ...
int a;
foo(a);
```

You have a lot of ways:

Pass uninitialized pointer by reference:

```
VOID GetOSVersion(PDWORD& major, PDWORD&, PDWORD&)
{
//...
major = new DWORD(osver.dwMajorVersion);

}
// usage:
PDWORD major;
GetOSVersion(major, ....);

//...
delete major;
```

Pass all parameters by reference:

```
VOID GetOSVersion(DWORD& major, DWORD&, DWORD&)
{
//...
major = osver.dwMajorVersion;

}
// usage:
DWORD major = 0;
GetOSVersion(major, ....);
```

Use your version of GetOSVersion(), but with the fix in this answer on the beginning

Comment: Your answer could be greatly improved by showing a simple sample how to initialize those variables properly.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that, the compiler says: "Cannot convert parameter 1 from PDWORD to PDWORD"

Comment: @user3718333 Is that really the error you get from the compiler? That seems strange. Can you paste the *exact* code?

Comment: @David Schwartz That is what I got when invoking with the code sample in the comment's first grey box. The code was exactly that + the function

Comment: @user2451677 You're going into a worse direction. Pointer references and `new()` aren't necessary here.

Comment: @David Schwartz no sorry, I misread it. I still declared the variables of type PDWORD just passed them as reference like &major. I did it wrong the answer is 100% correct.

Comment: @user3718333 **Consciously** select what you accept as an appropriate answer! Explain why you really need those `PDWORD major;` etc. pointers in 1st place.

Answer (score 5):

You are making the mistake that many make when it comes to functions that require pointer arguments.

When a function requires a pointer as an argument, it doesn't mean you blindly declare a pointer and pass it to the function.  What the function is asking for is an `address-of` an existing, valid, entity.

```
DWORD major, minor, build;
GetOSVersion(&major, &minor, &build);
```

The `DWORD`'s above are valid, and all that is done is pass the address of these variables to the function.

The other mistake that is related to this (not a bug, as it will give the desired results, but still a "mistake") is to declare a pointer, have it point to somewhere valid, and then pass it to the function.  In other words:

```
PDWORD major, minor, build;
major = new DWORD;
minor = new DWORD;
build = new DWORD;
GetOSVersion(major, minor, build);
delete major;
delete minor;
delete build;
```

or

```
PDWORD pmajor, pminor, pbuild;
DWORD major, minor, build;
pmajor = &major;
pminor = &pminor;
pbuild = &build;
GetOSVersion(pmajor, pminor, pbuild);
```

I have seen code written in this manner.  This indicates that the programmer does not have a clear understanding of what it means when a function requires a pointer as an argument.  The programmer erroneously believes that a pointer **must** be declared, have it point somewhere valid, and then pass this pointer.

Yes, you get the results without crashing, but it is a waste of time to call the allocator (new / delete), or if not calling the allocator, create unnecessary pointer variables which unnecessarily obfuscates the code.

So the easiest way is the first example above.  Just declare non-pointer types, and just pass the address.

Comment: +1 If any here, I think this answer explains best, what the probable misconception of the OP is!

Answer (score 2):

You probably meant to have your variable declarations and to call your function like this

```
DWORD major;
DWORD minor;
DWORD build;
GetOSVersion(&major, &minor, &build);
```

You use pointers to reference the output parameters, thus these need to point them to valid memory addresses. You can refer to those variables to get a valid pointer using the *'address-of'* (`&`) operator as shown above.

---

With c++ you can use by reference parameters, which will make things a bit clearer

```
VOID GetOSVersion(DWORD& major, DWORD& minor, DWORD& build) {
    OSVERSIONINFO osver;
    ZeroMemory(&osver, sizeof(OSVERSIONINFO));
    osver.dwOSVersionInfoSize = sizeof(OSVERSIONINFO);
    GetVersionEx(&osver);
    // Note there's no check needed if the pointers are valid!
    major = osver.dwMajorVersion;
    minor = osver.dwMinorVersion;
    build = osver.dwBuildNumber;
}

DWORD major;
DWORD minor;
DWORD build;
GetOSVersion(major, minor, build);
```

No need to call the `new()` allocator (and bother with correct dynamic memory allocation management) with any of the above samples in 1st place.

Answer (score 0):

Those are pointers. They are not pointing at any memory you have allocated. They do not get "filled" in the function, they get used to access (uninitialized) memory.

Answer (score -1):

You are probably not getting an error but a warning (but you might have configured your complier to treat warnings as errors).

If executed, your program will segfault because you are writing to the memory pointed to by them but as they are uninitialized they contain invalid/random addresses.

Possible solution

```
PDWORD major = new DWORD;
PDWORD minor = new DWORD;
PDWORD build = new DWORD;
```

assuming `PDWORD` is defined to be `*DWORD`.

Do not forget the deletes!

**edit: Actually its much more sensible to allocate these on the stack – see user2451677’s answer.**

Comment: Thanks @wonce. I before posting i tried allocating them as new PDWORD and now I get the point. Really a complete answer, thanks a lot!

Comment: -1 **No, No, No that's veeeery bad advice!** And certainly shouldn't be accepted! Think twice!

Comment: That is a bad solution.  It gives the impression that pointer arguments means that you must actually declare pointers.  You are needlessly calling the allocator.