# A variable is being used without initialized

Tags: c++, winapi

I am reading this http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/window_click.html 
and I am having trouble with the code. I am using VS 2012 and instead of `char*` or `const char*` I have to use `LPCWSTR` or `LPWSTR`.

In this particular case the problem is in the switch

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam,
    LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
        case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
        {
            LPWSTR szFileName;
            HINSTANCE hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);

            GetModuleFileName(hInstance, szFileName, MAX_PATH);
            MessageBox(hwnd, szFileName, L"This program is:",
                MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
        }
        break;
        case WM_CLOSE:
            DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
    break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I use `LPWSTR` instead of the char that is shown in the tutorial and I compile it but when I click on the window instead of showing the information window an error shows up :

`The variable 'szFileName' is being used without being initialized.`

As I understand it `GetModuleFileName()` should write the information in `szFileName` which is empty at beginning so I can't really understand what the problem is.

Comment: The tutorial does not pass in a `char*`; it allocates a buffer: `char szFileName[MAX_PATH]`. I can't understand why you randomly ignored that part of the tutorial!

Comment: You know `TCHAR` and the like are only for porting ancient windows apps to `wchar_t`? It's contraindicated in any other circumstances.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Fair enough.

Comment: @SlaviKalov - Please read the answer here, as it describes in general the issue you're having:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24472174/beginner-c-uninitialized-local-variable/24472249#24472249

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [the documentation for `GetModuleFileName()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms683197(v=vs.85).aspx):

> *lpFilename* [out]
>
> A pointer to a buffer that receives the fully qualified path of the module. If the length of the path is less than the size that the *nSize* parameter specifies, the function succeeds and the path is returned as a null-terminated string.

You are giving it a pointer, but it is a pointer into infinite chaos. You have not actually allocated a buffer.

Go ahead and do that now:

```
wchar_t szFileName[MAX_PATH];
GetModuleFileName(hInstance, szFileName, MAX_PATH);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare an array instead, LPWSTR is just a pointer

so change

```
LPWSTR szFileName;
```

to

```
wchar_t szFileName[MAX_PATH];
```

Comment: Better to use `TCHAR`, which will be `char` or `wchar_t` depending on whether or not Unicode is in use. Your version is more fragile.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: That presupposes that any app which is not being actively ported from ancient pre-NT windows to a more modern OS will actually be compiled both for UTF-16 and for `char`.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Yeah, okay.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Plus, if the code were being ported, and forgot to enable Unicode, then Claptrap's code would simply fail to compile, as it would be passing a `wchar_t[]` to `GetModuleFileNameA()` instead of `GetModuleFileNameW()`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: That's true either way.