# GetFIleVersionInfoSize() succeeds but returns incorrect size

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to get the version of a file. I want to look at the version number of this file to determine which OS is installed on a non-booted drive (I'll actually be doing this from a Win PE environment and trying to determine if the main drive has Windows XP or Windows 7 installed). Anyway, I have the following

```
wchar_t *fileName;
fileName = new wchar_t[255];

lstrcpy(fileName, hdds[HardDriveIndexes::SystemDrive].driveLetter.c_str());

lstrcat(fileName, L"Windows\\System32\\winload.exe");

TCHAR *versionInfoBuffer;

DWORD versionDataSize;

if (versionDataSize = GetFileVersionInfoSize(fileName, NULL) != 0)
{
    versionInfoBuffer = new TCHAR[versionDataSize];

    BOOL versionInfoResult = FALSE;

    versionInfoResult = GetFileVersionInfo(fileName, NULL, versionDataSize, versionInfoBuffer);
    if (versionInfoResult == FALSE)
    {
        wprintf(L"The last error associated with getting version info is: %d\n", GetLastError());
    }

}
else
{
    wprintf(L"The last error associated with gettting version info size is: %d\n", GetLastError());
}
```

The problem is that GetFileVersionInfoSize() succeeds but always returns 1 as the size. This causes GetFileVersionInfo() to fail with error 122. So far I have only tested this on a Windows 7 system. There is another function GetFileVersionInfoSizeEx() that works as expected, but it is only supported from Vista onwards. I would like to keep XP support if possible (some of our old Win PE images are still based on XP).

Is GetFileVersionInfoSize() deprecated and I somehow can't find that information, am I using it incorrectly, etc.?

Comment: Why are you allocating here, when you could have just declared an array of wchar_t? `wchar_t *fileName; fileName = new wchar_t[255];` You've introduced a potential memory leak for no reason. You also have another potential leak for `versionBufferInfo`.  Maybe you should read this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24472174/beginner-c-uninitialized-local-variable/24472249#24472249

Comment: As far as your error, I use `GetFileVersionInfoSize` and I give it an address of a DWORD variable as the second parameter instead of NULL.  It works for me, even in Windows 2K.

Comment: Dynamic memory allocation on the heap vs static memory allocation on the stack... Isn't that the only real difference as long as I watch out for the memory leaks? Or is there some general guideline that I have been missing? I've been programming C++ for about 5 years and didn't think it really mattered much and it was almost a matter of preference.

Comment: And also, @PaulMcKenzie I also tried doing that, and that DWORD just takes on a value of 0. It seems it is not used in NT based OS's

Comment: `is there some general guideline that I have been missing?` 1) What happens if you write code that could throw an exception, and thus the call to `delete` never gets executed later on?  Read up on `RAII` and what it does. Or quite simply, you just plain forget to call `delete`.  2) As to "a matter of preference", code that allocates an array with a constant value indicates (whether it is fair or not), that the programmer is not experienced.  Quite simply, writing code in the style that you have done is more or less, outdated.  Yes, it works, but is not recommended in this day and age of C++.

Comment: consider using `vector` instead of `new`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thanks for the tip and I see the confusion now. There are other arrays I have in my code that were dynamic so I followed the same pattern. It makes sense that if you know the size of the array it should not be allocated this way. I'm sure it also doesn't help that I'm not primarily a C++ programmer, but mainly .NET, PHP, JS, Python, and other more "dynamic" languages. Thank you for the advice, even though I didn't think it pertained to my question. I do try to get more out of coming to this site than just getting an immediate question answered. I'd rather better my skils.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem isn't with the call, it's with your assignment; you need parens around it:

```
if ( ( versionDataSize = GetFileVersionInfoSize(fileName, NULL) ) != 0)
```

What you had written assigns the value of the expression `size != 0`, which is 1 for true.

Comment: Happens to everybody sometimes :)