# Passing a pointer vector into a function

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I'm missing one simple reference which I cannot seem to find online The print_vector function needs a second parameter(the pointer vector).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void print_vector(ostream& os, vector<int>*);

int main()
{

int b =100;

vector<int>* a = new vector<int>;

for(int z=0; z< a->size() ; z++)
{

    a-> at(z)= b;
    b++;
}


print_vector(cout,  a);

delete a;

return 0;
}


void print_vector(ostream& os, vector<int> a)
{
for(int c =0; c <= a.size(); c++)
{
     os << a[c] << endl;
}


}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You are accessing the vector out of bounds. You need `for(int c = 0; c < a.size(); c++)`

Comment: Also declaration and definition of `print_vector` dont match

Comment: Nope, that might be a fault but the major flaw lies with the parameters of print_vector being called in main

Comment: howcome they dont match?

Comment: There is no need to dynamically allocate the vector. `vector<int> a;` is sufficient.

Comment: @user3504476 - OK, so you declared a function that takes a pointer.  That doesn't mean you literally have to declare a pointer, call `new` to initialize it, and pass that pointer.  All you needed to do was create a vector and pass the *address* of that vector using `&`. `vector<int> a; ... print_vector(cout, &a);`

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to use the reference, but you can try both:

```
using namespace std;
void print_vector(ostream& os, const vector<int>& aVec);
void print_vector(ostream& os, const vector<int>* aVec);
int main()
{
    int b = 100;
    vector<int> a;
    for(int z=0; z < b; z++)
        a.push_back(z);
    print_vector(cout,  a);
    print_vector(cout,  &a);
    return 0;
}
void print_vector(ostream& os, const vector<int> &a)
{
    for(int c=0; c < a.size(); c++)
        os << a[c] << endl;
}
void print_vector(ostream& os, const vector<int> *a)
{
    for(int c=0; c < a->size(); c++)
        os << (*a)[c] << endl;
}
```

upd: thx to juanchopanza advice of using const reference

Comment: Even better to use a `const` reference.

Comment: Just implemented that and im still receiving the same error message

Comment: undefined reference to `print_vector(std::ostream&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >*)'

Comment: look attentively at the declaration, that i propose to you. Use it, and it'll be ok.

Comment: error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'std::vector<int>&' from expression of type 'std::vector<int>*'|

Comment: error: in passing argument 2 of 'void print_vector(std::ostream&, std::vector<int>&)'|

Comment: if you use a reference, than should provide an object, not address. I rewrite total example for your case. It is surely compiled.

Answer (score 1):

First of all it is not clear what you are trying to do in this code snippet

```
int b =100;

vector<int>* a = new vector<int>;

for(int z=0; z< a->size() ; z++)
{

    a-> at(z)= b;
    b++;
}
```

As the allocated vector is empty then the loop will be iterated never.

As for the function then  you should exchange parameters: the first parameter should be reference to a vector.

For example

```
void print_vector( const std::vector<int> &v, std::ostream &os = std::cout )
{
   for ( int x : v ) os << x << std::endl;
}
```

The program can look like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void print_vector( const std::vector<int> &v, std::ostream &os = std::cout )
{
   for ( int x : v ) os << x << std::endl;
}


int main()
{
    const int N = 100;

    std::vector<int> v;
    v.reserve( N );

    for ( int  i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        v.push_back( i );
    }


    print_vector( v );


    return 0;
}
```

If you indeed need to use a pointer to a vector then code can look like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void print_vector( const std::vector<int> &v, std::ostream &os = std::cout )
{
   for ( int x : v ) os << x << std::endl;
}


int main()
{
    const int N = 10;
    const int INITIAL = 100;

    std::vector<int> *v = new std::vector<int>;
    v->reserve( N );

    for ( int  i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        v->push_back( INITIAL + i );
    }


    print_vector( *v );

    delete v;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The point of the program is to create a vector using the free store, increment the values starting at 100 and then print it using the ostream function

Comment: @user3504476 - In all honesty, those are really dumb requirements.  All it does is enforce bad habits and actually holds you back from learning how to properly write a C++ program.

Comment: @user3504476  It is not clear how many elements of the vector should be filled with values starting from 100.:)

Comment: Lets just say for example the vector holds 10 elements'

Answer (score 0):

First, let's assume you don't want to change the `print_vector` function signature.  Without trying to figure out exactly what your program is supposed to accomplish, this should compile:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
void print_vector(ostream& os, vector<int>*);

int main()
{
    int b =100;
    vector<int> a;
    for(int z=0; z< a.size() ; z++)
    {
        a.at(z)= b;
        b++;
    }
    print_vector(cout,  &a);
    return 0;
}


void print_vector(ostream& os, vector<int>* a)
{
    for(size_t c =0; c < a->size(); c++)
        os << (*a)[c] << endl;
}
```

Here are the changes:

1. The `print_vector` function takes a pointer.   What that means is that the function requires the `address-of` an existing vector.  Note how in the `main()` function, the vector is an object, and all I did was pass the address (no need for `new`).  Please see this answer for information on functions that ask for pointers as arguments: [Beginner C++ uninitialized local variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24472174/beginner-c-uninitialized-local-variable/24472249#24472249)
2. The `print_vector` function's loop was changed from `<=` to `<`.  If not, you were going out of bounds, causing undefined behavior.
3. In `print_vector` note that `operator []` needs to get handled differently when a pointer is passed.  The pointer was dereferenced before applying `operator []`.  The other syntax for this is `a->operator[](c)`, but that's a little more verbose.