# Code crash on get method, C++

Tags: c++, pointers, crash, boolean, double

I basically have a `bool` get function which returns `true` or `false` and sets the values.

This is my method...

```
bool Student::getMarks(int i, double *a, double *b)
{
    {BOUNDS CHECKNG DONE HERE...
     return false;}


    THE LINE BELOW WORKS FINE AND PRINTS TO TERMINAL
    //cout << marks[i][0] << "," << marks[i][1] << endl; 

    //THIS BIT CRASHES THE PROGRAM
    *a = marks[i][0];
    *b = marks[i][1];
    return true;
}
```

This is my test program...

```
Test.cpp
double *a;
double *b;
Student student;

case 1:
    student.getMarks(i, * a, *b);
    cout << *a  << endl;
    cout << *b << endl;
    break;

default:
    break;
```

If a mark exists it returns true and sets the mark to `*a` and `*b`.

However, the program crashes.

Would greatly appreciate it if someone could tell me where I am going wrong. I want it so that the test program actually returns both `*a` and `*b`

Comment: You are dereferncing uninitialized pointers: `student.getMarks(i, * a, *b);`! That's just undfined behavior.

Comment: Your code snippet won't even compile, so it cannot be the real code.

Comment: What are `x` and `y`?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, Apologies, that should have read `a` and `b`

Comment: Ahh, then it's obvious. `a` and `b` don't point to anything, yet you try to dereference them.

Comment: @SamThers - You suffered from this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24472174/beginner-c-uninitialized-local-variable/24472249?s=4|0.0616#24472249

Answer (score 2):

You want this:

```
double a;
double b;
Student student;

case 1:
    student.getMarks(i, &a, &b);
    cout << a  << endl;
    cout << b << endl;
    break;
```

Comment: Changing the function to take references would probably be better.