# how to detect or avoid using C++ uninitialized pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers

I got an uninitialized pointer problem today. unfortunately, it caused core dump after it released.

here is the sample code, and the function print_request() is new code, and this function could be used by several other functions:

```
// def.h
struct INFO {
  uint32_t val1;
  uint32_t val2;  
};

struct INFO_LIST {
  uint32_t id;
  struct INFO * data;
};

// util.cpp
void print_request(const struct INFO_LIST req)
{
  fprintf(stdout, "%u\t%u\t%u\n", req.id, req.data->val1, req.data->val2);
}

// A.cpp
int parse_ie(...)
{
  // ...
  struct INFO_LIST req;
  req.id = 10;
  req.data = new INFO();
  req.val1 = 101;
  req.val2 = 102;

  print_request(req);

  // ...
}
// B.cpp
int parse_chrome(...)
{
  // ...
  struct INFO_LIST req;
  req.id = 20;

  print_request(req);  // core dump here!

  // ...
}
```

here is what I have done:

1. I have wroten the unit test for print_request(), but I forgot there is an uninitialized pointer while function parse_chrome() use it.
2. I analyzer the code by using the static code analyzer tool, for example, cppcheck, and there is no error or warning.
3. it is still ignored after code reviewing.

so, I want to know:

1. is there any good tool to detect the uninitialized pointer in C++?
2. how to avoid using uninitialized pointer in C++?

any suggestion would be appreciated, thank you!

PS, I want to write uniform functions to call the pointer, but it would cost much time.

PPS. sorry, variable "req" is not a pointer. my fault.

Comment: You mean an "uninitialized" pointer, and most compilers definitely do provide a warning for that.  What compiler are you using?

Comment: For that matter, `parse_ie` dereferences an uninitialized pointer also.

Comment: I think you're getting confused when a function asks for a pointer as one of its arguments:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24472174/beginner-c-uninitialized-local-variable/24472249#24472249

Comment: In `int parse_ie(...)`, are the three dots (A) C++ syntax for variadic argument function, or (B) indication that there are some arguments but you'd omitted them for brevity? In the case of (B), please add a clarifying comment. And yes it is relevant for an answer to your question. Be precise. Always.

Comment: By the way, the C++ standard's term for what you have is an **indeterminate value**. Except for `char` types it's Undefined Behavior to use an indeterminate value.

Comment: Most compiler will give you error "The variable 'req' is being used without being initialized". Which one are you using ?

Comment: Define 'empty pointer'. Do you mean null? Uninitialized?

Comment: `req->id = 20;` <- are you sure you didn't get a core dump HERE?

Comment: Please review MCVE definition -- the code you show should compile.  And C and C++ are different languages.

Comment: I use g++ 4.2 to compile my code.

Comment: "empty pointer"  == uninitialized.

Comment: You did detect it, by getting a core dump. The core dump will contain the full stack, allowing you to locate and fix the problem. If this isn't what you want, explain what you want. Do you want to detect this at compile time? Do you want to detect it at run time? Do you want to 100% guarantee you always get a core dump if you do this? Or what?

Comment: I want to detect it before it is released. and I also want to get a core dump before it is released. but in fact, I find it after it is released. so, it is late.

Comment: to hyde: I could not use valgrind, because our code would process the requests without a break except it is killed.

Comment: There is no such thing as empty pointer. If you mean "uninitialized pointer", please update the question.

Comment: That won't stop you using valgrind

Comment: to n.m.: I change the title, sorry.

Comment: to David Heffernan: if the server would stop by itself, valgrind could collect the data about memory leak. and you could not get the data if you kill it.

Comment: After cleaning up your example by removing the '...' cppcheck is capable of detecting this uninitialized pointer usage. The cleaned source code is available [here](https://gist.github.com/orbitcowboy/ac8b91b98cc8fbc1c478). Here is the output of cppcheck:  cppcheck test.cpp 
Checking test.cpp...
[test.cpp:37]: (error) Uninitialized struct member: req.data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, add a default constructor to `INFO_LIST`:

```
struct INFO_LIST {
  uint32_t id;
  struct INFO * data;
  INFO_LIST() : id(0), data(nullptr) { ; }
};
```

Second: Throw an exception in `print_request`:

```
// util.cpp
void print_request(const struct INFO_LIST req)
{
  if (! req.data->val1 || ! req.data->val2)
    throw (std::runtime_error ("Uninitialized pointers"));
  fprintf(stdout, "%u\t%u\t%u\n", req.id, req.data->val1, req.data->val2);
}
```

If you want to catch this at compile time:

```
struct INFO_LIST {
  uint32_t id;
  struct INFO * data;

  INFO_LIST (struct INFO* d) : data(d) { ; }

  private:
  INFO_LIST () { ; }
};
```

Now you will get an error at compile time if you try to construct an `INFO_LIST` without initializing the `data` pointer.

Comment: thank you, I remember to write the defensive code like your second suggestion except this time, so I get one core dump. the reason I ask this question is that I want to know wheather there is a better method than I remember to write the defensive code.

Comment: @MarkZ. See update, now that I know you want to make it impossible to compile code that creates an `INFO_LIST` without an initialized `data` field.

Comment: thank you, your suggestion is what I want. but I get errors if I add "INFO_LIST() = delete;" in the sample code,  and the errors are : error: invalid pure specifier (only `= 0' is allowed) before ';' token; error: initializer specified for non-virtual method 'INFO_LIST::INFO_LIST()'

Comment: it would be ok if I comment "INFO() = delete;" out.

Comment: I am sorry, it is "INFO_LIST() = delete;", not "INFO() = delete". could you tell me why should I add this line?

Comment: @MarkZ. I'll edit the question to show a better way.

Comment: thank you very much, I would refactor my codes as your suggestion!

Comment: Off-topic: what's the point of writing `{ ; }` instead of just `{}`?

Answer (score 0):

You have created a struct pointer at line `INFO_LIST * req;`, remove a `*` to create a struct instead. Currently you are using a bare pointer (of type struct INFO_LIST) to nothing.

Comment: yes, it is my fault, I should not add the "*" in the sample code. thank you.

Comment: @mark-z now you are using structs, so change all ->  to dots . but I guess you can solve it now :)

Comment: I want to get a better method to solve it. maybe I forget to use the uninitialized variable in future, and I hope there is a way which could help me to find it before it is released.

Answer (score 0):

> How avoid using a c++ empty pointer?

Your code looks like c, to me. The languages are different, pick one or the other.

---

As to your question title:

In C++, you can use the non-nullptr value tested as:

```
if(ptr) ptr->doSomething();
else    doSomethingElse();
```

NOTE that pointers are POD, and must be explicitly initialized.

So

```
MyObject* ptr = new MyObject;  // default ctor
assert(nullptr != ptr);        // check for success
```

or

```
MyObject* ptr = nullptr;  
// later code sets the pointer to something
```

I prefer to use the slightly more clear:

```
if(nullptr != ptr) ptr->doSomething();
```

Comment: `ptr` is an actual instance of `MyObject` and not a pointer to one. And of course, this sort of testing works just as well in C as it does as in C++. One problem is that it *only* works if you initialize your pointers to `nullptr` in C++ or `NULL` in C.

Comment: @NikBougalis - yep - thanks.  too close to sleep time ... I woke up thinking about it.  Change applied