# How to convert from a string to a double to a double*

Tags: c++, double

I'm learning C++ so this may be a basic question, however, it is a real life problem. I need to convert from a string to a double and then in turn to a double* in the most elegant/modern way possible (>C++98).

The structure is provided by a C based framework (I've simplified the code here as this is the crux of the problem only) and I cannot change the framework as this interfaces with the closed source Metatrader4 trading application (non C based). The programming interface requires a pointer to be passed to the structure.

The strings are being read from a csv file containing a dump which I have taken from the Metatrader4 application. The details of which are beyond this problem. However, the inputs remain strings hence are the origin type.

I appreciate the method used in the framework may be old skool but that's part of life. It doesn't mean that I can't aspire to do something better in my code, hence the reason I asked for elegant/modern solutions. If they don't exist then I'll be forced to use new as someone has already suggested.

I currently have the following none working code:

```
#include <string>

struct bidAsk
{
    double *bid;
    double *ask;
};

int main()
{
    bidAsk ba;
    ba.bid = std::stod("1.100");
    ba.ask = &std::stod("1.102");
}
```

However, both of the above conversion methods fail with conversion errors.

The first line results in an error which states:

```
E0513   a value of type "double" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "double *"
```

The second line results in the following error:

```
E0158   expression must be an lvalue or a function designator
```

I've also tried static_cast, const_cast, make_unique and (double*) casting with no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Who should own memory of the `double` ? `ba.bid = new double(std::stod("1.100"));` might be a solution...

Comment: I should have mentioned that the string is fixed too. 

The double (non pointer) isn't necessarily owned by anyone. The strings are coming from a csv file and the structures requires a double pointer so was using the double (non pointer) as an intermediary step only. If there are better ways of converting a string to a double * then I'll be interested in those methods too. 

I don't want to use new as I concerned about memory leaks etc. Hence the reason I said elegant/modern ways.

Thanks for asking.

Comment: There is no "good" way to do it.  The object having raw pointers like that is just asking for trouble.  As Jarod mentioned `ba.bid = new double(std::stod("1.100"));` is probably the easiest way.  You just have to remember to call `delete` on those pointer once you are done with them.  If this is your teacher doing this you should as why they are using pointers as the data members.

Comment: Please, I'm not a student! This is a real life problem. Perhaps, a better way might be to use ba.bid = make_unique<double>(std::stod("1.100")) ?

Comment: It would be but you can't assign a `unique_ptr` to a `double*`.

Comment: ok, just a thought. Also, the reason the structure is using pointers is that the underlying thing that I'm interfacing with is C based which I don't have easy access to.

Comment: C does support value mechanics so a `struct bidAsk
{
    double bid;
    double ask;
};` would be legal and free you from pointer insanity.

Comment: The only reason to use pointers in a struct is because the things pointed to already exist elsewhere and something else uses them at times. A struct with pointers to a double is a very odd duck. You need to include more code that shows the way those are used elsewhere as there really is no other realistic reason.

Comment: Thanks Doug, updated the description will feedback from everyone's comments

Comment: `std::stringstream f; double k;   f << "1.00";    f >> k;`

Comment: Why does it have to be `double*` instead of just `double`?

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин not bad. A performance hit perhaps?

Comment: @JamesAdkison It's a C based framework which interfaces with an external close source trading application (Metatrader4) so I can't change that I'm afraid.

Comment: Yes it needs a pointer and I've tried (see my example) passing it a reference but  the stod errors when I do. I may have done something wrong of course but that may be due lack of knowledge.

Comment: @Andrew [Please read this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24472174/beginner-c-uninitialized-local-variable/24472249#24472249), and decide if you are making the same mistake.  I bet you are.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie has a good reference answer linked and [my answer](https://ideone.com/244u4B) makes the same point. Assuming that answer is applicable you can probably just delete this question.

Comment: ____________ no

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I don't believe that I am.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you need some actual values for your *pointers* to point at. They can't just point at the temporary values returned from your *number conversion functions*.

```
struct bidAsk
{
    double* bid;
    double* ask;
};

int main()
{
    bidAsk ba;

    // these have to exist somewhere that lives as long as the
    // bidAsk object that points to them.
    double bid_value = std::stod("1.100");
    double ask_value = std::stod("1.102");

    ba.bid = &bid_value; // just pointing to the real values above
    ba.ask = &ask_value;
}
```

Comment: I was hoping that it could do without the intermediary step of creating temporary values. If it can't then fair enough.

Comment: @Andrew It depends a lot on how you interface with your framework and what it expects from you. Is this `struct` part of the framework or just something you made? How are you calling the framework? Could you put some exampled in your question?

Answer (score 1):

As others mentioned in the comments, someone has to own the objects, the pointers are pointing at.

```
extern C {

struct bidAsk
{
    double *bid;
    double *ask;
};

}

struct BidAskWrapper
{
  BidAskWrapper(const std::string& sbid, const std::string& sask) 
                       :bid{std::stod(sbid)}, ask{std::stor(sask)} 
  {}         
  //Note: bidAsk valid only till the lifetype of the wrapper
  bidAsk make_c_struct() {
    return {&bid, &ask};
  }
  double bid, ask;
};
```

Comment: I'm actually interested in version greater than C++98 as stated in the question so a modern version would be interesting.

Comment: Which modern version 11, 14 or 17?

Comment: Don't mind. The most elegant solution only matters to me (with performance of course)

Comment: I don't think there is anything special about your problem where you'd have to resort to some new C++ features. I think Galik's answer is more than good.