# C program reads BOM in reverse (Go left... No! The other left)

Tags: c++, endianness, byte-order-mark

I'm ... confused.
Here's the thing. I've got an *ini file encoded as UNICODE (Little Endian).
In my project in Visual Studio (my own ini parser) I'm checking if text file has got BOM (Byte Order Mark) at the begining of file.

From wikipedia:

11111111 11111110 (0xFFFE) - little endian BOM,

11111110 11111111 (0xFEFF) - big endian BOM.

So far, I'm right, right?

So it's time for little code:

```
size_t temp_val = 0;
wchar_t * endianness_val = new wchar_t;
temp_val = fread_s(endianness_val, sizeof(wchar_t), sizeof(wchar_t), 1, fp);

    if (*endianness_val == (wchar_t)0xFFFE)
    {
        endianness = 1;
        wprintf(L"\n UNICODE(16bit): Little Endian!");
    }
    else if (*endianness_val == (wchar_t)0xFEFF)
    {
        endianness = -1; //big endian
        wprintf(L"\n UNICODE(16bit): Big Endian!");
    }
    else
    {
        endianness = 0; //no BOM, little endian default
        wprintf(L"\n No BOM. Narrow characters (8bit) Assuming Little Endian!");
    }
```

I'm reading (using fread_s) first wchar_t from file and I'm storing it in endianness_val. Everything seems to be good:

- *ini file HAS Byte Order Mark(0xFFFE),
- looking into memory (debuging) gives me the same result - endianess varable stores 0xFFFE.

Aaaannd Visual Studio keeps going into if statement for Big Endian (like a maniac ;)). Of course changing BOM for Big Endian results in Visual Studio entering correct if statement.  Any ideas why this works backwards?

Thanks.

Comment: Unrelated, the reason(s) behind dynamically allocating a single `wchar_` as opposed to just using a `wchar_t var;` and `&var` for the read target perplexes me. Is the `&` key on your keyboard broken ?

Comment: I'm also unsure why this question is tagged C when you are using the C++ `new` operator

Comment: @WhozCraig --Probably a [victim of this issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24472174/c-uninitialized-local-variable/24472249#24472249)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running the following code on your text file open in `fp` and see if it helps you catch your *conceptual* error:

```
uint8_t bytes[2];
uint16_t word;

fread(bytes, 1, 2, fp);
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
fread(&word, 2, 1, fp);
fclose(fp);

wprintf(L"%.2hhX %.2hhX\n", bytes[0], bytes[1]);
wprintf(L"%.4hX\n", word);
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response and very useful example, but... honestly I don't get why this happens. Seriously.

Comment: Oh, I can edit coment only for 5 minutes. Maybe my thinking is simply wrong:
When I look at my *ini file (as binary file), the first 16 bits are 11111111 11111110.
So I thought that it doesn't matter if I will interpret these bits as 2 separate bytes (FF FE) or one two byte variable (FFFE). I'm definetelly missing something. Anyway, again thanks for response ;)

Comment: @VIGOR_PICTURES Byte order (little endian vs big endian) only makes sense at the level of bytes. Your code doesn't read bytes.

Comment: @melpomene Exactly what I was trying to demonstrate with my answer

Comment: Ok, I am dumb. I thought that endianness works on bits (basiclly entire multibyte variable is in reverse). Heh, thats what you get when not reading about something by yourself and hearing from someone else.

Comment: @VIGOR_PICTURES There is such a thing as [bit-endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_numbering); it's just very seldom that you need to deal with it in typical C code.