# returning pointer to a struct, how can I free memory automatically?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, smart-pointers, raii

To return a big struct "MODULEENTRY32" from WINAPI I want to use a pointer, but need to allocate memory in the heap inside the function without deleting it. Then, out of the function when I don't want to use that struct anymore I know that I should use the keyword delete to free memory.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <TlHelp32.h>

MODULEENTRY32* GetModuleEntry(const char *module_name, int PID)
{
    HANDLE moduleSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE | TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32, PID);

    if (moduleSnapshot != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        MODULEENTRY32 *moduleEntry = new MODULEENTRY32;             // Remember to delete if don't want leak
        moduleEntry->dwSize = sizeof(MODULEENTRY32);

        if (Module32First(moduleSnapshot, moduleEntry)) {
            do {
                if (strcmp(moduleEntry->szModule, module_name) == 0) {
                    return moduleEntry;
                }
            } while (Module32Next(moduleSnapshot, moduleEntry));
        }

        CloseHandle(moduleSnapshot);
    }

    return nullptr;
}

int main()
{
    int myRandomPID = 123;

    MODULEENTRY32* p = GetModuleEntry("mymodule.dll", myRandomPID);

    if (!p) {
        std::cout << "Obviously you didn't found your random module of your random PID " << std::endl;
    }

    delete p;   // I just don't want to do this

    return 0;
}
```

How could I avoid having to free memory in main function? **unique_ptr**?

**EDIT: Possible solution**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <TlHelp32.h>

bool GetModuleEntry(const char *module_name, int PID, MODULEENTRY32* moduleEntry)
{
    HANDLE moduleSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE | TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32, PID);

    if (moduleSnapshot != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        moduleEntry->dwSize = sizeof(MODULEENTRY32);

        if (Module32First(moduleSnapshot, moduleEntry)) {
            do {
                if (strcmp(moduleEntry->szModule, module_name) == 0) {
                    CloseHandle(moduleSnapshot);
                    return true;
                }
            } while (Module32Next(moduleSnapshot, moduleEntry));
        }

        CloseHandle(moduleSnapshot);
    }

    return false;
}

int main()
{
    int myRandomPID = 123;

    MODULEENTRY32 moduleEntry;

    if (!GetModuleEntry("mymodule.dll", 123, &moduleEntry)) {
        std::cout << "Obviously you didn't find your random module of your random PID " << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, `unique_ptr`. That's exactly the sole reason for its existence. Maybe `shared_ptr`, too.

Comment: A struct is copyable as-is.  There is no need in resorting to pointers -- just return the `struct`.  Let me guess -- you're calling a function that requires a pointer to a `MODULEENTRY32`, so you assumed you *must* declare a pointer and use it, am I right?

Comment: [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) is a useful addition to @PaulMcKenzie 's suggestion. For more reading, [What are copy elision and return value optimization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization)

Comment: @OP [Are you making this mistake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24472174/c-uninitialized-local-variable/24472249#24472249).  Other than the link uses `DWORD`, it seems you're making every mistake pointed out in that answer.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie do you mean pass the struct as out parameter via pointer?

Comment: Simply pass the address-of a MODULEENTRY32.

Comment: Note that the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/toolhelp/traversing-the-module-list) even shows to do without _creating_ a pointer

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Well really... how I didn't guess that? thanks I usually pass a lot of out parameters via pointer but this time I only wonder about return the pointer.

Comment: Do not return the pointer -- actually return the full struct.  A `struct` is copyable.  Or return a type (such as pointed out by @user4581301) that contains a full struct (a `std::pair<bool, MODULEENTRY32>` or similar).  Contrary to what many newbies believe, you can pass and return `structs` around by value -- all the copy semantics will hold.

Comment: Also, it looks like you left the function without closing the handle.  Sounds like a reason to also use RAII.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yes but woudn't be better to declare a struct MODULEENTRY32 in main, pass it's address to the function GetModuleEntry("mymodule.dll", myRandomPID, &module) and then work directly with that inside the function and returning a bool or nothing (void).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yes I forget CloseHandle(moduleSnapshot) inside the conditional.

Comment: If the function returns a `bool`, you have to return `true` or `false` -- there is no "void" return if the function returns `bool`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie look the EDIT now I meant that.

Comment: Please see my answer.  Changing the function parameters is a matter of taste, but the bottom line is that you do not need dynamic allocation whatsoever.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie ok Thanks Paul I didn't know anyting about **copy elision**, it seems not exensive at all. The only think that I don't like is the std::pair.

Comment: @EduardoG The `std::pair` technique is used in a few STL functions.  For example `std::map::insert`, `std::unordered_map::insert`, and a few others utilize this technique of returning a success code and an item.

Comment: With C++17 structured bindings the `std::pair` thing gets even nicer.  You can do something like `auto [success, moduleEntry] = GetModuleEntry(...);`

Comment: @MilesBudnek, I don't like C++11, 14 and 17, prefer to stay close to C-Style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you refrain from pointers, and simply return the full `MODULEENTRY32` struct by value.

I also suggest that you can wrap the return type in a `std::pair<bool, MODULEENTRY32>` or similar type, so that you can record an error return if necessary.

Lastly, you are not closing the handle if you find the module name.  A little bit of [RAII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) could be used to ensure that the `HANDLE` is closed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <TlHelp32.h>
#include <utility>

// Helper struct to automatically close the handle
struct ModuleRAII
{
    HANDLE *h;
    ModuleRAII(HANDLE* h_) : h(h_){}
    ~ModuleRAII() { CloseHandle(h); }
};

std::pair<bool, MODULEENTRY32> GetModuleEntry(const char *module_name, int PID)
{
    HANDLE moduleSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE | TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32, PID);

    if (moduleSnapshot != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        // This will close the handle automatically
        ModuleRAII raii(&moduleSnapshot);

        MODULEENTRY32 moduleEntry = {};
        moduleEntry.dwSize = sizeof(MODULEENTRY32);
        if (Module32First(moduleSnapshot, &moduleEntry)) {
        do {
            if (strcmp(moduleEntry.szModule, module_name) == 0) 
                  return {true, moduleEntry};
           } while (Module32Next(moduleSnapshot, &moduleEntry));
        }
    }
    return {false, MODULEENTRY32()};
}

int main()
{
    int myRandomPID = 123;
    auto retVal = GetModuleEntry("mymodule.dll", myRandomPID);
    MODULEENTRY32& p = retVal.second;    
    if (!retVal.first) {
        std::cout << "Obviously you didn't found your random module of your random PID " << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This basically is a fail-safe implementation of the function.  It hasn't been tested, but shows the various techniques used, all without dynamic allocation.

Note that the function returns a `std::pair<bool, MODULEENTRY>`, so basically the parameters remain the same.  The only difference is that you obtain the information by accessing either `first` (to test whether the function failed or not), and `second`, for the actual `MODULEENTRY`.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Return a unique_ptr from the getModuleEntry function itself.

```
unique_ptr<MODULEENTRY32> GetModuleEntry(const char *module_name, int PID)
{
    HANDLE moduleSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE | TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32, PID);

    if (moduleSnapshot != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        unique_ptr<MODULEENTRY32> moduleEntry = make_unique<MODULEENTRY32>();             // Remember to delete if don't want leak
        moduleEntry->dwSize = sizeof(MODULEENTRY32);

        if (Module32First(moduleSnapshot, moduleEntry.get())) {
            do {
                if (strcmp(moduleEntry->szModule, module_name) == 0) {
                    return moduleEntry;
                }
            } while (Module32Next(moduleSnapshot, moduleEntry.get());
        }

        CloseHandle(moduleSnapshot);
    }

    return nullptr;
}
int main()
{
    int myRandomPID = 123;
    std::unique_ptr<MODULEENTRY32> s_ptr = GetModuleEntry("mymodule.dll", myRandomPID);

    if(s_ptr.get()==nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << "Obviously you didn't found your random module of your random PID " << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```