# C++ Segmentation fault when changing value of pointer within method call

Tags: c++, pointers, methods, parameters, segmentation-fault

I'm programming a server - client application with a shared utils.cpp.

So the server and client use the (in utils.h) predefined methods:

```
int listening_socket(int port);
int connect_socket(const char *hostname, const int port);
int accept_connection(int sockfd);
int recv_msg(int sockfd, int32_t *operation_type, int64_t *argument);
int send_msg(int sockfd, int32_t *operation_type, int64_t *argument);
```

So far, so good.

But since the recv_msg() just returns if it was successful or not I need to handle the transmitted operation_type and argument via pointer modification. At this point I am kind of lost.

My goal is to set the method parameters (the int32_t *operation_type and int64_t *argument pointer) to the transmitted values. In server.cpp I have initialised the int32_t * and int64_t * in order to pass them into the recv_msg() method (also tried to give them a value e.g. = 0).

server.cpp:

```
...
int32_t *operation_type; // with = 0; also Segmentation fault
int64_t *operation_type; // with = 0; also Segmentation fault

if (recv_msg(server_socket, operation_type, argument) == 0)
        printf("In server.cpp: operation_type: %" PRId32 " and argument: %" PRId64 " \n", operation_type, argument);
```

In utils.cpp the method I am trying to change the pointer's value via:

```
int recv_msg(int sockfd, int32_t *operation_type, int64_t *argument) {
   // some buffer and read() stuff...
   // trying to change pointer's value 
   operation_type = (int32_t *)1;
   // also tried 
   *operation_type = 1;
   // and same thing with the int64_t * argument pointer
   int64_t  argu = message.argument(); // also tried this
    *argument = argu;

    printf("In utils.cpp: operation_type: %" PRId32 " and argument: %" PRId64" \n", operation_type, argument);
```

Ether I don't change the points values, so in method they have the wanted value, but after executing the recv_msg() the points value is 0 again or I get a **Segmentation fault**.

I understand the basics of pointers and references, but I am used to Java and new to the "*" and "&" prefixes.

My question: How do I can modify pointers which are passed as parameters in a imported method, or I am ready the int32_t and int64_t wring?

Comment: I imagine that when using 'operation_type = (int32_t *)1;' your printf shows 0 and when you use ' *operation_type = 1;' , you got a Segmentation Fault. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, Exactly it does

Comment: @Chillaui [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24472174/c-uninitialized-local-variable/24472249#24472249).  When a function is asking for pointer arguments, it doesn't mean you declare a pointer and pass it to the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pointers are variables  that should be use to point to some allocated memory.

In your initialization, you made your pointers point to NULL, i.e, no memory.

And after that you are trying to change the value of nothing. That's why you are getting a segmentation fault.

You should either:

Declare some local variables and make your pointers point to them. Something like:

```
int32_t local_type_operation;
type_operation = &local_type_operation;
```

Or use some dynamic memory allocation function to allocate some memory to point to (search about `malloc`).

Comment: Honestly, there is no need for a temporary pointer variable if the function being called is asking for the address of something.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24472174/c-uninitialized-local-variable/24472249#24472249), as it seems your answer suggests taking a roundabout approach.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone! I finally understood it and make it work!

Here a video recommendation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7HmCb343xR8

Also my dummy code in which I experimeted:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int changePointer(int32_t *type, int64_t *argu);

int main(int args, char *argv[])
{
    int32_t type = -1; // declare local varibales
    int64_t argu = -1; 

    printf("\nPre-ChangePointer:\n   type: %d at %d\n   argu: %lld at %d\n\n",
           type, &type, (long long)argu, &argu); // Debug print

    changePointer(&type, &argu); // call mathod to change pointers value

    printf("\nPost-ChangePointer:\n   type: %d at %d\n   argu: %lld at %d\n\n",
           type, &type, (long long)argu, &argu); // Debug print

    return 0;
}

int changePointer(int32_t *ptr, int64_t *ptr2) // ptr and ptr2 are copies of type_ptr and argu_ptr
{
    *ptr = 2;  // change value of type_ptr
    *ptr2 = 2; // change value of argu_ptr

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: I guess you missed the point I made in the main comment section.  There is no need for the `type_ptr` and `argu_ptr` variables.  All they add is unnecessary clutter, exactly as the answer I linked to points out.  You could have just had `changePointer(&type, &argu);`.  Writing code in the way you've written it indicates you really didn't understand fully what is meant when a function requires a pointer as an argument.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @PaulMcKenzie, you are right! I now have edited my answer. Should be clean now, or?